# VBA references in exe

Tags: vba, reference, exe

I recently made an Excel-tool, which makes heavy use of VBA macros. 
This tool works perfectly on my pc, and on most of my colleagues pc's, but I noticed that it doesn't work on some other pc's. This is because some of the required reference files are not present on those pc's.

I would like to solve this by making an exe-file of the original Excel document, in which all the referenced files are included. I already tried this with Winrar, but I noticed that, after unpacking the exe, the reference files are unpacked in the folder in which the exe file was copied, but not in the required system folders.

How can I fix this, so that I can use the tool on whichever computer I'd like to?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards, 
Marc

Comment: You might want to check the license for those files you want to distribute. If they belong to Microsoft Excel, you'll be in violation of your agreement if you distribute them.

Comment: Could you describe which files are you trying to distribute? I'm not concerned about licensing, as I _understand_ you already checked that, but is important to understand which files are lacking in your user's PCs.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is due to missing reference files ? Have you modified your code in order to use late binding ? This can solve the problem of files being just "somewhere else".

Answer (score 1):

Michael Todd's comment about licensing is something worth checking up, but assuming that's ok, you could just write a simple batch file and/or script to first unrar the files and then copy them into the relevant directories. This script would preferably be executed during installation of your excel document.

However, depending on what files they are I'd would be wary of copying them into system directories. Firstly, will you have permissions to write to those directories? Secondly, is it possible that you'll overwrite other versions of those dlls, possibly overwriting a newer version with an older version. Depending on what DLLs you're trying to copy, you might break other applications or even Windows itself by copying them in.

In general, if the solution to your problem is to copy random dlls from your machine to someone else's machine, you should look for an alternative solution. I'd suggest that the better solution might be to change your application to not reference those dlls, or if that can't be done, do a proper install of the application where those dlls come from on the machines where you have the problem .

Comment: Hi everyone, licensing indeed is not a problem, I'm trying to distribute the following files: rend.dll, MSWord.odb and the MODI folder (Microsoft Office Document Imaging) which contains the folder 12.0 > 1043 with mspfltrs.dll and msplcres.dll.

Comment: @belisarius: I'm afraid so... Do you know any other more reliable software or freeware to make the exe?

Comment: @marc: The best way would probably be to use some kind of setup builder software that usually makes it easy to install files wherever you need to. If you've got access to Visual Studio there is one built in there (look for setup project). Otherwise the only one I remember the name of is WISE, but I'm sure there's plenty around.

Answer (score 0):

---

Just to be sure:

Winrar shows something like this:

[image]

and you should be selecting either "Store full paths" (better) or "Store full paths including drive letter" (worse)

Comment: I think this could lead to issues unless the windows installations are in the same places. For example, if he has windows installed in `C:\Windows` on his machine, but one of the other users has it installed as `D:\WinNT` or something, then I think it might fail (though this depends on exactly what is meant with System folders in the question though, I assume it means the `Windows\System32` folder and similar).

Comment: @ho1 Agree. A full solution should take care of where system folders really are. But my guess is that target machines are vanilla clients with a standard folder layout ...

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you try [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php#qsp).  It has a higher initial learning curve, but it is **well worth it** for the enhanced functionality over WinRAR (for this type of thing).  Inno-Setup creates installers from plain-text setup files, however, the "Quick Start Pack" includes a GUI front-end for making this part easier.